# Why can't the root DNS server need to direct to authoratative server?

Tags: dns

So from what I learned, the root DNS server will direct the query for url/IP matching to an authoritative server if the root server doesn't contain that information. Why can't the DNS root server just hold all the information?

Answer (score 1):

A root DNS server will not really "direct the query". It will send a referral. The recursive resolver that receives that referral is expected to follow it. Also, there is no query for "url/IP". URLs are not found in DNS (notwithstanding `NAPTR` records).

DNS is a hierarchical, distributed database that was specifically designed to alleviate the scaling problems inherent in a centralized database that contains everything, which is what we had before DNS (the old `HOSTS.TXT` file).

Asking the root servers to "just hold all of the information does away with both the hierarchical and distributed nature of the DNS database, which puts us back in the problematic, non-scalable situation we were in to begin with. Not to mention that it is impossible to do at this point due to the sheer amount of information in DNS and how often it changes.